# SQL programming logic - beginner level

Tags: sql

I am a beginner at SQL programming. Any pointers would help me.

```
Table 1                 
Server id   Appl id     
1           1           
1           2          
1           3           
2           4           
2           5           
3           6
```

Aggregate the values like this need not output

```
Server ID   Appl id

1          1 2 3

2          4,5

3          6
```

Server id/Appl id present in same column of this table2

Pick up the mktd id values based on appln id for the server 1 from table 2

```
Appln id    Mkt id  Record no       
1             10    1       
1             20    2       
2             45    1       
3             45    1       
3             10    2
```

Then enter mkt id values for server 1 in table 2

```
Server id   Mkt id  Record no       
1             10    1       
1             20    2       
1             45    3
```

Comment: You should post your table structures, sample data and expected results, along with what you attempted.  Sounds like a basic `join` though...

Comment: Have you done any research on basic SQL usage and couldn't find anything helpful?

Comment: would be good to have table structure, sample data

Comment: Edited the question. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having 3 tables. tblServer, tblApplication and tblMarkup. Here you wanted to pull out the mark up id's based on the server name..

Then you need to join server table with application first and then join the application table with mark up using the related columns and in the where filter you can mention the server name . Sample code is given below.

```
    SELECT m.MarkupId
    FROM tblServer s
        JOIN tblApplication a on s.serverId=a.serverid
        JOIN tblMarkup m on a.ApplicationId=m.markupId
     WHERE s.ServerName= 'Your Server'
```